# How to execute some function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some snippet of code

```
  public onChange(event: Event) {
      this.loadFiles();
  };


  loadFiles() {
    let files = event.target['files'];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
          this.list.push(infoFile);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  loadImage() {
    this.imageService.setImage(this.list);
    this.isClicked = true;
    this.imageLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
  }
```

I'm new in javascript and I would like to execute `loadImage()` function afer `onChange()`. I try using something like this in `loadFile()` i try using something like this inside `loadFiles()`

```
     let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(this.list);
      });

      promise.then(response => {
        this.imageService.setImage(this.list);
        this.isClicked = true;
        this.imageLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
      });
```

but this code execute for each iteration loop for. Maybe is possible execute `loadImage()` function inside `onChange()` function only one ? I also try something like that

```
    public onChange(event: Event) {
    this.loadFiles();
    let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
      this.loadFiles();
      console.log(this.list.length);
      resolve('success');
    });
    promise.then(response => {
      console.log(this.list.length);
      //this.loadImage();
    });
  };
```

but promise execute faster than `loadFiles()` and length is equals 0.

Comment: Seems like you need async flow.
by default  its sync flow. Though i will suggest you to use some async library.

Comment: Sidenote: if (FileReader) will throw an error when there is no filereader

Comment: I also change ImageServices set is as global in app.module.ts because when i add it to component.ts the services was reloaded and array became empty.

Comment: I change approach and don't use promise only add  if (this.loadedFiles == this.allFiles) in loadImage() method

Comment: Somedy know how it's work when i put Service in component providers section that this service is reloaded after or before loaded component using this service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to execute the load Image after onChange but if you want you can easily execute if you put this code

```
public onChange(event: Event) {
  this.loadFiles();
  setTimeout(loadImage, 100);
};
```

But I saw that you want to execute the loadImage after you populate the this.list if you want to use promise you can use this way:

```
public onChange(event: Event) {
  let myPromise = new Promise(this.loadFiles);
  myPromise.then(this.loadImage).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};


loadFiles(resolve: () => void, reject: (_: string) => void) {
  let files = event.target['files'];
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
        this.list.push(infoFile);
        resolve();
      };
      try {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

loadImage() {
  this.imageService.setImage(this.list);
  this.isClicked = true;
  this.imageLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
}
```

I think you want a method what first reads all the files and after call the loadImage method with that list, so maybe I would do this way:

```
public onChange(event: Event) {
  this.loadFiles();
};


loadFiles() {
  let files = event.target['files'];
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
        this.list.push(infoFile);
        if (this.list.length === files.length) {
          this.loadImage()
        }
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
  }
}

loadImage() {
  this.imageService.setImage(this.list);
  this.isClicked = true;
  this.imageLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
}
```

Note: I didn't used type script much so maybe the paramerters are different.

Comment: are you suggest that better use onClick() method ?

Comment: I think you want a method what first reads all the files and after call the loadImage method with that list, so maybe I would do this way

Comment: exactly first i all reads all files and affter call loadImage that contains setImage in service i would haveh this image shared bettween all components.

Comment: i try use your example but is problem i have error that imageService is undefined. I use him as global provider in app.module.ts and inject it in constructor.

Comment: so right now you have the this.list, and it goes in the loadImage, but the imageService is undefined, hmm.... Can I see how you inject it ?

Comment: constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {} and providers is in app.module.ts i don't use this service in this component

Comment: I don't worked on angular but I guess you need to add this to your constructor constructor(private imageService: ImageService) { this.imageService = imageService}

Comment: in angular when you use something like this constructor(private imageService: ImageService) compilator automaticly create  { this.imageService = imageService} and i don't must write this line in code.

Comment: ah okay then, fr that why is it undefined I can not say anything, I didn't used angular

Answer (score 0):

This is solution that work i resigned for used promise

```
  public file_srcs: string[] = [];
  loadedFiles: number = 0;
  allFiles: number = 0;
  list: string[] = [];
  isClicked: boolean = false;
  @Output() imageLoadedEvent = new EventEmitter < boolean > ();

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  public onChange(event: Event) {
    this.loadFiles();
  };

  loadFiles() {
    let files = event.target['files'];
    let promises = [];
    this.allFiles = files.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
        console.log(infoFile);
        this.list.push(infoFile);
        this.loadedFiles++;
        this.loadImage();
      }
      if (fileReader && files && files.length) {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  loadImage() {
    if (this.loadedFiles == this.allFiles) {
      this.imageService.setImage(this.list);
      this.isClicked = true;
      this.imageLoadedEvent.emit(this.isClicked);
    }
  }
```